# Codeigniter session problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I've created user authentication using an awesome [codeigniter authentication library ion auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) in my codeigniter application, the authentication works fine but when i logout and click back button of the browser i can go through all the pages that i've visited in my application which raise concern aver user privacy but if i try to refresh the page it recognises that I'm logged out. How can i force the browser to reload when a user click back button of the browser? Any suggestion on how to solve this problem will be appreciated..

**EDIT**

Controller logout function

```
function logout() {
    //log the user out
    $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

    //redirect them back to the page they came from
    redirect('auth', 'refresh');
}
```

This is logout function from [ion auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)

```
public function logout() {
    $this->ci->ion_auth_model->trigger_events('logout');

    $identity = $this->ci->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth');
    $this->ci->session->unset_userdata($identity);
    $this->ci->session->unset_userdata('group');
    $this->ci->session->unset_userdata('id');
    $this->ci->session->unset_userdata('user_id');

    //delete the remember me cookies if they exist
    if (get_cookie('identity')) {
        delete_cookie('identity');
    }
    if (get_cookie('remember_code')) {
        delete_cookie('remember_code');
    }

    $this->ci->session->sess_destroy();

    $this->set_message('logout_successful');
    return TRUE;
}
```

I'm using codeigniter 2.0.3

Thanx in advance..

Comment: show some code... I bet you don't check on each page for "is logged in" thats probly why, only done at login. Need to check per page in your 'secure area'

Comment: I do check it thats why when i reload the page it redirects me to the login page it looks like the page is not reloaded when someone logout

Comment: maybe you don't quite log out, its hard to say without any code, post a typical controller setup, as I've never had this issue with sessions on CI.

Comment: They are actually logged out, however the pages you're able to see still are those which the browser has cached.

Comment: @Jakub I've edited my question. I log out and this can be proved when i try to click any link or reloading the page as am being redirected to the login page.

Comment: how do i prevent the previous pages content from showing when the user has been logged out? @BenSwinburne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chances are they are in fact logged out (as you say, refreshing causes them to appear logged out). It is likely that the browser has cached the HTML which is displayed indicating they're logged in but doesn't reload it after they're logged out.

You can set the pages which have login related information on to no cache by setting the `Cache-Control` header.

This can be achieved with HTML

```
<META Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

Or PHP

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

You can also implement the hacky and inadvisable clearing the user's history for that particular window using the following code. This would need to be sent to the browser as part of the logout functionality and would not work if the user has javascript disabled.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
     var Backlen=history.length;   
     history.go(-Backlen);   
     window.location.href=page url
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Thanx a lot @Ben Swinburne.. it was caching problem. I achieved this in codeigniter by adding `$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");` at constructor of each controller except the authentication controller.

Comment: Try to redirect at database interaction functions in your controller level instead of disabling caching.

Comment: @SamSamson:  I don't see why would you no-cache everywhere except "authentication controller" . I think ion_auth like everyone uses sessions. So no-cache should be ok in "authentication controller" as well.

Answer (score 1):

I highly discourage disabling caching, as this will reduce the speed of your app. I had the same problem because of silly coding, what I did was in my controllers, I put the following code at the top of every function which interacted with the database, used by the users in logged in states:

```
//Do not let anyone interact with database from cached pages!
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    }
```

So that redirection to login page happens, which means a refresh as well, if a logged out user's browser was "backed" to a cached logged in state and tried to fiddle with the database.

Answer (score 0):

yes ion auth has this problem i was facing the same problem in my application. anothr problem was if session expire on any link it takes you to login page. but when you logged in and you try to access last link where session expired it always take you back to login page. to access the page you need to clear your browser cache. here is solution i found on github comments on ion auth

[github ion-auth comment link](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/issues/398)

```
function logout() {
    //log the user out
    $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

     header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
     header("Expires: Wed, 4 Jul 2012 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

    //redirect them back to the page they came from
    redirect('auth', 'refresh');
}
```